# Why do I still have Green Checkmarks on my desktop folders

Tags: windows-10

Why do I have these green checkmarks on my icons?
I have refreshed my desktop and they are still there.

Comment: What green checkmarks? Consider posting a screenshot.

Comment: Have you used the `rebuild icons` command yet?

Answer (score 0):

With big probability you set those directories to be sync with OneDrive. And green check mark indicate they are in sync in this moment.